# How to get Restful API up and running using Wt

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, wt

I have a running Wt application based on the tutorials all over the web and I was wondering if there is an elegant way of using Wt to add a some Restful API functionality.

I have a few resources I can expose from my current application and I don't want to implement any patches.

If someone has a good idea of how to do that, or even a suggestion of some JSON library that can make the development a breeze, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should subclass `WResource` and implement the `WResource::handleRequest` method to provide REST API functionality. Then you should add your resource to your server using `WServer::addResource`

Also you should ensure that you add your resource to the server before the main Wt appliaction entry point:

```
Wt::WServer server(argv[0]);
server.setServerConfiguration(argc, argv, WTHTTP_CONFIGURATION);
server.addResource(new MyResource, "/api"));
server.addEntryPoint(Wt::Application, createApplication);
```

Comment: Why is it important to add the resource before the entry point?

Comment: Oh, implementing it like http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/4358 , but with a `WApplication` entry point, then on every path refresh, it tries to re `addResource()`, which throws a fatal error.  Implementing it as per this answer for some reason blocked me from reading from my configuration file.

Comment: Hmm, it's too late to edit my comment.  Turns out I should be reading config options off the `WServer`, not `WApplication`.. Sorry for spamming this answer with comments :S