# Web toolkit (Wt) based api

Tags: web, wt

I am trying to make api for a WebGIS application, can I use Wt framework to make the api or Wt framework can be used only for building web application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Restful API up and running using Wt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860068/how-to-get-restful-api-up-and-running-using-wt)

Comment: thank you @hank , the link gives me an idea of how to achieve what i am trying to do. But I have one more doubt if I write my api using Wt would the calling web application should also be based on Wt as I have a lot of custom widgets, will those custom widgets can be called from other webpages using other technologies other than Wt.